# Trait in type bound "not implemented"?

Tags: rust, traits

Consider the following code, which uses a trait to make the length of an array fixed in the type.

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;

pub trait MyLen {
    const LEN: usize;
}

pub struct Data<L: MyLen> {
    bytes: [u8; <L as MyLen>::LEN],
    _phantom: PhantomData<L>,
}
```

I could swear I saw similar code work a couple days ago, but now I'm seeing

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0277]: the trait bound `L: MyLen` is not satisfied
 --> src/lib.rs:8:17
  |
4 |     const LEN: usize;
  |     ----------------- required by `MyLen::LEN`
...
8 |     bytes: [u8; <L as MyLen>::LEN],
  |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `MyLen` is not implemented for `L`
  |
help: consider further restricting this bound
  |
7 | pub struct Data<L: MyLen + MyLen> {
  |                          ^^^^^^^

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `playground`
```

This error message doesn't make sense to me, especially not the suggestion. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=49c9a11106a46125eaa9612560966bac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you'll need to use the [`const_generics` feature](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2000-const-generics.html) to be able to do that. However, that's not entirely enough, as you'll also need to use the [`const_evaluatable_checked` feature](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/unstable-book/language-features/const-evaluatable-checked.html).

When you add the `const_generics` feature, then the issue becomes apparent with a more descriptive compiler error.

```
error: constant expression depends on a generic parameter
  --> src\main.rs:37:12
   |
37 |     bytes: [u8; <L as MyLen>::LEN],
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: this may fail depending on what value the parameter takes

error: constant expression depends on a generic parameter
  --> src\main.rs:34:30
   |
34 |     [u8; <L as MyLen>::LEN]: Sized,
   |                              ^^^^^
   |
   = note: this may fail depending on what value the parameter takes
```

The missing part is `where [u8; <L as MyLen>::LEN]:`  (or `where [u8; <L as MyLen>::LEN]: Sized`) which requires the `const_evaluatable_checked` feature. The where clause is needed, to ensure that `LEN` doesn't evaluate into something that overflows or otherwise invalidates that array.

You can read more about it on this [HackMD post](https://hackmd.io/OZG_XiLFRs2Xmw5s39jRzA?view) by the Rust Compiler Team.

```rust
#![feature(const_generics)]
#![feature(const_evaluatable_checked)]
#![allow(incomplete_features)]

use std::marker::PhantomData;

pub trait MyLen {
    const LEN: usize;
}

pub struct Data<L: MyLen>
where
    [u8; <L as MyLen>::LEN]: ,
    // or
    // [u8; <L as MyLen>::LEN]: Sized,
{
    bytes: [u8; <L as MyLen>::LEN],
    _phantom: PhantomData<L>,
}
```

Which of course requires a nightly compiler to build.

Comment: Wouldn't `[u8; size_of::<L>()]` be a more clear implementation than this "size marker" trait workaround?

Comment: @IvanC Unless I missed some context, then I don't see where the question mentions that `LEN == size_of::<L>()` :)

Comment: I might have misinterpreted the code, but it seems like the intent is to have Data own a "raw" u8 buffer for storing L and since being generic over differently sized Ls using associated const would limit you to one buffer size per L anyway, size_of seems like a straighter path to that goal.

Comment: @IvanC Definitely a possibility. But I'll keep the answer as is, literally reflecting the question. Until/Unless OP changes the question :)

Comment: I was aware of const generics but tried to find a workaround without having to use experimental language features, thus the size marker traits. So basically you're saying this isn't possible?

Comment: @Heinzi If you want to literally do, as in your question. Then no, that isn't possible on stable. If you're willing to change design, then there's likely possible workarounds, depending on the overall context :)

Comment: thanks, what kind of workarounds would you attempt? Context is simple enough, I want to write a type that holds a fixed-size array and I don't want to duplicate code for different sizes.

Comment: @Heinzi min_const_generics feature is due to stabilise in next release, so you might consider being generic over <N: usize>

Comment: @Heinzi Feel free to add an example to your question of how you implement `MyLen` and use it, and then I can add an example of what @IvanC said, and/or something else if that's more fitting